# Execute an instruction every x seconds in a for loop of an arraylist using JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I think this question has already been answered but I can't find the right solution to my problem.

I have a arraylist containing several "ball" objects. I want to browse this list to "shoot" each ball with x seconds between them.
Here is the code I have, I tried with the *Timertask*, *System.currentMillis()* / *nano* but I can't find a solution that works.

```
for(Ball ball: ballList) { // Browse the list
   ball.setMove(true);     // Launch ball

   // Wait x seconds before sending new one
   // ...
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Thread.sleep() or TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep() which is a wrapper on Thread.sleep() for better readability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But im not in a thread and sleep() stop my entire program, im looking for a solution without sleep if you have ;)

Comment: You are always in a thread even if it’s the main thread. But if you don’t want to stop your whole program you can run the ball thrower in a separate thread. Another option is, if you have a loop, to keep track of how much time passed since the last throw and throw a ball if sufficient time has passed.

Comment: @DarkMatter I see thank you. I'll try to manage this based on the time spent.